# Java and JFrame "NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, noclassdeffounderror

I am new to Java and especially to JFRAME. I am studying about basic game development and I created a simple class to output some graphics. Here is my code:

```
package jframedemo;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class JFrameDemo extends JFrame {
    public JFrameDemo(){
        super("JFrameDemo");
        setSize(400,400);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }    

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,400,400);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 18));
        g.drawString("Doing graphics with JFrame!!", 60, 200);
    }

   public static void main(String[] args){
       new JFrameDemo();
    }
}
```

Although during compile everything goes as well, when I try to execute  the programm I get the following error:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JFrameDemo (wrong name: jframedemo/JFrameDemo)**

I am working on Linux Mint 15 and my Java version is 1.7.0_25 OpenJDK Runtime Environment. Any suggestions why is this happening?

Comment: OT: You dont want to do custom painting in top level containers in Swing. Extend a JPanel and override `paintComponent`

Comment: Instead of creating folders manually that represent a package, instead use the `-d` option of `javac`. Create a folder called `project`, inside this create two folders namely `source(to keep .java files)` and `build(to place file once compiled)`. Now simply come to `project` folder through terminal, and write `javac -d build source/JFrameDemo.java` this will automatically create a folder named `jframedemo` inside `build` folder. Now from inside `project` folder, write `java jframedemo.JFrameDemo` to execute the program. More options can be seen by simply typing `javac` at the terminal :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `JFrameDemo.class` is not in a folder called `jframedemo` as expected by the JVM. Ensure that the `JFrameDemo.java` is located in this folder before attempting to compile and run the application

Then your command line commands will look like

```
javac jframedemo/JFrameDemo.java
java jframedemo.JFrameDemo
```

Comment: Ths actually worked! Although I don't quite get it...is there some kind of tutorial or something on this topic? I mean, I created a folder named jframedemo and moved in it my ".java" file. Then compiled and ran it as you told and it worked. How come this solved the problem?

Comment: Because the JVM requires that the class exist in a directory structure that match the package name

Comment: Yeap, it got to me a little after I posted my comment :) Thanks a lot!